Macro doesn't stop when I expect it to stop
I was tasked with creating a breakeven macro for a project and am having trouble stopping the loop once the check value is fulfilled.
Sub Breakeven()
Dim i As Long
Sheets("Financials").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 9).Select
i = 100000
Do Until Range("A10").Value = 0
i = i + 200
ActiveCell.Value = i
Debug.Print i
Loop

End Sub

A10 is a percentage that increments from a negative value as i increases. My breakeven point occurs when A10 equals 0%.
When I run the macro, it doesn't stop when A10 = 0%, but rather keeps incrementing i until I break the macro. I'm assuming my issue has something to do with the A10 check looking for a number rather than a percentage, but this is my first step into VBA and I haven't been able to find any information on syntax that helps my case.

Carrying over Staging comment from @FrankBall - "Are you sure that your formula in A10 will be equal to exactly "0"? If it's 0.000001, your loop will never end but most likely what you see in the cell will be "0%". Try setting the Until condition to either less than 0 or greater than 0 (depending on which direction you're approaching the value from) and see what the value in A10 is at that point."

Just use the condition >= 0 instead of = 0 if your values are increasing.
